# How will be changed Hill's radius and Kepler's formulas in case of 2D space instead of 3D?

Tags: solar-system, gravity, space, newtonian-gravity

Imagine that Flatland habitats go into space. All stars and planets are the circles instead of spheres and gravity law is $F=Gm_1m_2/R$ instead of $F=Gm_1m_2/R^2$.

How the other formulas will be changed in this case?

Answer (score 3):

The "orbits" in this case have no closed-form in terms of circular or elliptic functions.  The locus of the body will tend to fill space in an annular region around the central point.

This image of a $F=-1/r$ orbit was produced by "[central force workbench](http://tp.lc.ehu.eus/jma/mechanics/central.jar)" by Juan M. Aguirregabiria.

The potential is now of the form $V= \ln|r|$. The only formula that is unchanged is Kepler's second law: Equal areas are swept out in equal time, as this is true for all central forces.

[image]